# Lower back strength-training and running for tennis

Tags: strength-training, back, tennis

I have been building muscles half a year successfully. 
I today run first time for a long time 1.5 hours. 
I feel a kind of good tension or gentle pain at my middle back (T10). 
I have not had a similar feeling although played now about 20 tennis matches this summer.

I thought that foam roller would be enough to keep the back in good shape while building mass. 
Apparently, it is not enough. 
I play also tennis but its effects to the back are not similar to those in running.

I started to think what is a good training program for lower back while building muscles. 
At the moment, I have

- some squats
- some elastic thing to do squats and other stretching movements
- foam roller

I am already using the stretching gum and gymnastics daily. 
However, the feeling of running and effect of thumbing on the back is something I cannot achieve other ways. 
Probably, I should add more rapid pushes to my stretching movements. 
However, I have tried to avoid these.

**What is a good lower back strength-training program when building muscles?**

Comment: Work deadlifts into your routine.  Also what is "stretching gum"?

Comment: This kind of thing https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-05%20at%2017.43.39.png Not sure what is the exact name of it.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Yes, deadlifts - I need to add to my practice. I have added recently some squats too which may help.

Comment: Squats are just a great exercise regardless (as are deadlifts).  Squats will increase leg strength more than anything, which in the long run will assist in helping pull the deadlift those first 5 inches off of the floor.  IF YOU ARE A BEGINNER WITH DEADLIFTS OR SQUATS, PAY VERY CLOSE ATTENTION TO FORM.  Form is extremely important on deadlifts and squats to reduce chance of serious injuries.

Comment: This [q/a](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4324/how-can-i-strengthen-my-lower-back/4327#4327) may help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a barbell and rack, do some of the recommended items of back squats and deadlifts. Those alone will make a phenomenal difference in your back strength. They're tremendously valuable compound lifts.

They're also somewhat technical so find some good tutorials or books (Rippetoe is someone I personally recommend). Start with lighter weights, initially just the bar, and work up from there.

If you don't have access to a gym (and even if you do) you might want to consider some bodyweight "lifts". Two of my favorites for lower back and hamstrings are single leg Romanian deadlifts and supermans. Bret Contreras is another name (along with Rippetoe) that you can reliably count on for good information that thousands of athletes have sworn by.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyV3rwv62AE (SLRDL)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cc6UVRS7PW4 (Superman)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kawBY5p29fQ (Squat)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWRTHOMq-n8 (Deadlift)